# Icon on Toolbar doesn't open Navigation Drawer and doesn't disappear itself when scrolling

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I'm trying to implement NavigationView in tandem with Tabs.
So, here's activity code:

```
public class DashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        init();

        decorate();

        setListeners();
    }

    private void init() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    }

    private void decorate() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new EventsFragment(), getString(R.string.all_events_tab));
        adapter.addFrag(new EventsFragment(), getString(R.string.soon_tab));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And **main_activity.xml** hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ... />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.DashBoardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

**There are two problems:**

1. Hamburger icon on Toolbar doesn't open Navigation Drawer
2. The Toolbar doesn't disappear when scrolling

What have I missed in the implementation? And what could be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show complete app_bar_main.xml?

Comment: @GPack has made a change in the post.

Comment: have you tried without snap flag?

Comment: Yes, I tried an incredible amount of different combinations :)

Comment: I think the problem may be in the content fragments of ViewPager: there must be a view that implements NestedScrollingChild interface, like RecyclerView or NestedScrollView

Comment: @GPack Apologies for the delay in replying. In fact, there was a `ListView` in the fragment, which I replaced with `RecyclerView`. It helped!

Answer (score 2):

Add this piece of code to your Activity for solving the problem of Hamburger Icon.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  // OPEN DRAWER
            return true;
        ....
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And for the toolbar part, have you tried putting layout_scrollFlags like this..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)` works, but `"scroll|enterAlways"` flags didn't help me.

Comment: @MarkKorzhov I don't know exactly what type of behavior you want. However follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html) and put the type of `layout_scrollFlag` you want